# "There is a tear on her face"

Tags: word-usage

How do I describe this?

[image]

Is this one clear?

> "There is a tear on her face"

Comment: Or, *she's crying.* Putting the emphasis on the tear rather than her is a little odd.

Comment: @JasonBassford Thank you. There are lots of form of crying. What if the photographer was trying to emphasize only one drop of tear?

Comment: In that case, it might be more natural to title the photograph something like *Woman with a Tear*, which still puts the emphasis more on the woman than the tear itself. When I hear *there is a tear on her face* (as opposed to something else), I think to myself, *I wonder how it got there?*

Comment: I would say *A tear rolling down a woman's face*